# HINT: Symmetric difference of sets is associative

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know there are proofs online, but I don't want to see a whole proof and cheat myself out of the experience of figuring it out for myself. In that spirit, I've been stuck for a while and would really appreciate a hint.

I was thinking of doing a proof where I take an arbitrary x from LHS and show it must be in RHS and vice versa but that feels too elementary.

Comment: One approach is to show that $(A\triangle B)\triangle C$ and $A\triangle(B\triangle C)$ are both equal to the set of things that belong to an odd number of the sets $A,B$, and $C$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** There's an approach interesting using *indicator function*. I will write a little about that:

---

The *indicator function* of a set $A \subset X$ is defined by $$\textbf{1}_{A}(x):=\left\{\begin{aligned} 1, \quad x \in A\\ 0, \quad x\notin A \end{aligned} \right.$$

Using that, you can prove that $$\textbf{1}_{A\triangle B}=\textbf{1}_{A}+\textbf{1}_{B}-2\textbf{1}_{A}\textbf{1}_{B}=\textbf{1}_{A}+\textbf{1}_{B} \pmod{2}$$
and then you can use that for to prove that $$A\triangle (B\triangle C)=(A\triangle B)\triangle C$$
where $A,B,C$ are subsets of  $X$ and $A\triangle B:=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$.